# XeLaTeX passes to Inkscape wrong path when exporting svg

Tags: xetex, compiling, svg

Here's my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\author{}

\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath
  {
  {./images/svg/}
  }
\begin{document}

\newpage

\includesvg{src/images/svg/demo.svg}

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:182359): WARNING **: 17:28:44.888: Can't open file: /home/mykola/Projects/Latex/images/svg/demo.svg (doesn't exist)

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:182359): WARNING **: 17:28:44.888: Can't open file: /home/mykola/Projects/Latex/images/svg/demo.svg (doesn't exist)
ink_file_open: '/home/mykola/Projects/Latex/images/svg/demo.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /home/mykola/Projects/Latex/images/svg/demo.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!



Package svg Warning: The export with Inkscape failed for file
(svg)                `images/svg/demo.svg'
(svg)                Troubleshooting: Please check in the log file how
(svg)                the invocation of Inkscape took place and try to
(svg)                execute it yourself in the terminal on input line 2.


! Package svg Error: File `demo_svg-tex.pdf' is missing.

See the svg package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

The file is actually in `./src/images/svg/demo.svg`

As you see, it passes the wrong path (namely, my `~`) for Inkscape. How can I handle it?

**UPDATE:** now it finds the file. The reason was that it seems, `\graphicspath` has no connection to the `svg` I import.

Comment: your tex file is incomplete so no one can run this or debug you have specified `./images/svg/demo.svg` relative to the working directory of the xetex process (not relative to the document) but you have not said what that directory is, or which directory holds the svg file.

Comment: actually, package `svg` evaluates `\graphicspath` but only for files given without any path. Giving `\includesvg{demo.svg}` would search the working directory `./` as well as `./images/svg/` for the file. That's identically to `\includegraphics`. Regarding your log snippet, the desired file was actually found, otherwise Inkscape wouldn't have been invoked by package `svg`. So maybe, Inkscape is setup in an unfamiliar way.